# How do I make timer2 run the function only once if the process is running?

Tags: c#

In this function I'm checking if the game us running or not.

If it's running I'm starting the `backgroundworker`.

Then in `timer2` I keep checking if the process is running until I will quit the game.

But I don't want it to keep checking if it's running or not and start the `backgroundworker` all over again and again...

So in one side I want that `timer2` will run the function all the time until I quit the game in the other hand I don't want it to start the `backgroundworker` all the time.

```
private void wichProcessIsrun()
{
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("BFBC2Game");
    if (pname.Length == 0)
    {
        Logger.Write("Battlefield Bad Company 2 Ended");
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.Write("Battlefield Bad Company 2 Started");
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wichProcessIsrun();
}
```

Comment: I can check if the backgroundworker is busy but then again it will check it all the time and also it's writing to the log file all the time if the game ended or started many times. I need everything to be doing once but also somehow to keep watch the process untill i quit the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `bool` variable which you should set when you start the process and after, during checks, just check its value, if it's `true` than you shouldn't start the `backgroundworker`.
**EDIT:**
You should check if the process had already been started before it has ended. You should put the started variable in the `if` clause, than you will log only after the process was running for some time.

```
    bool started = false;
    private void wichProcessIsrun()
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("BFBC2Game");
        if (pname.Length == 0 && started)
        {
            Logger.Write("Battlefield Bad Company 2 Ended");
            started = false;
        }
        else if(pname.Length != 0 && !started)
        {
            Logger.Write("Battlefield Bad Company 2 Started");
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            started = true;
        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wichProcessIsrun();
    }
```

Comment: Nikola that's great another thing when im running the application and the game is not running yet so it's writing to the log file all the time that the game is ended since timer2 is working every second. But the game is not ended since it didn't run yet. How can i realy check if the game is ended(quited when i quit the game) ?

Comment: Now it's checking if the game is not running as process so it will write to the log file all the time that the game is ended i need somehow to check only if i quit the game then if the process is not in the list but was in the list before that's mean i quited the game.

Comment: @m.t.bennett I thought that he is using the program only once when the game is started, but you are right, started should be reset to false when Quit is detected. Thanks

Comment: Nikola i see started already in the if statement , where to put another started and how make it complex ?

Comment: Ah you mean in the Ended place to put the started = false ?

Comment: It's working. One last thing if it's possible to check that if the game is already running and i quit the program not the game only the program and run it again so it will not write anything to the log file. Now if the game is running and i quit the program and run it again it will write again that the game is started. How can i make that if the game is running already and i quit the program and run the program again it will not write again that the game is started since the game is already running ?

Comment: In that case you should write somewhere that the last time the program has been running, it detected that the game has started. That "somewhere" is most probably in your case registry but can also be a file or database in general case. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) for instance how to write to registry (only then the program is closing) and how you can read it when it starts.